# Difference Between .at(vect.size())=x; and vect.push_back(x);

Tags: c++, stdvector

Is there any difference between

```
int x{5};
std::vector<int> vect;
vect.push_back(x);
```

and

```
int x{5};
std::vector<int> vect;
vect.at(0) = x;
```

Comment: Yes. You will figure it out quickly if you try it.

Comment: Bookmark [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) and make it your best friend.  Go there _all the time_ and you will learn a lot without having to ask.   For now, just [read this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

Comment: I did which is exactly why I asked the question, the case vect.push_back(x) threw an exception whereas vect.at(0) worked, which was the opposite of what I expected.

Comment: I would attribute that result to user error.  Try to repeat the experiment from scratch.

Comment: @Jack You can [edit] your question at any time to provide additional info. This is better than adding a comment. It will help people write answers, so will benefit you.

Comment: If you have an error that's inconsistent with your expectations, you should [edit] your code to make it a [mcve] and describe your results (ideally with a paste of the error message or exception detail).

Comment: @all I now realise this is a problem with the ROOT interpreter. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes there is small difference - first works, second does not.

Answer (score 4):

[std::vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) will allocate memory for the object and  insert into the container.

[std::vector:at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) meant to use to retrieve the existing object using index. If the object is not present in container it will throw exception

Answer (score 2):

`push_back` pushes a new object into the vector. `at` returns a reference to an existing object. If the index is out of bounds such as in your example code, `at` throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vector.push_back` to fill an empty vector. But using `vector.at()` since that the `vector` is empty, it throws an exception.

---

Except:

```
std::vector< int > vector( 10 );  // for 10 integer
vector.at( 0 ) = 3;
std::cout << vector[ 0 ] << '\n'; // 3
```